# PhoneGap/Cordova Android get screen size after onDeviceReady

Tags: android, cordova

Android app returns invalid size (320x480) on `onDeviceReady` event, but after few seconds size becomes correct.

How can we get correct size at the very beginning? Or is there any event on which I can get correct size?

I'm using this function to get size:

```
function getWindowSizes() {
  var windowHeight = 0, windowWidth = 0;
  if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
      windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      
  } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      
  } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
     windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
     windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  }
  return [windowWidth, windowHeight];
}
```

Viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Using Cordova 2.5.0.

UPD: 
As you can see on this screenshot application launches with smaller size. Even empty Cordova project does this. How can I fix this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: any progress in that matter? Any of the answers worked for ya?

Comment: I have the problem, any progress?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not developing Cordova applications anymore. If I have time I'll try to reproduce and check following solutions. But if it doesn't work for you, it won't work for me neither.

Answer (score 3):

Remove height, width and density properties on meta header index.

Comment: I use <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove target-densitydpi in the header.

device dpi is based on physical pixels while css pixels are logic pixels, they are some times different from each other, if you force them to the same, you'll see screen stretched.

window.devicePixelRatio may give you result of the conversion.(On webkit)

Update:

This link provide some more details on how it works:
https://petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/

Comment: Firefox provides a value for `window.devicePixelRatio` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the position:absolute property in the app class (inside index.css). This works for me.